# Lotusscript agent vs. Java agent - any performance differences?

Tags: lotus-domino

I'm working on my API which has many of the features done by Lotusscript. Java API is being used mostly in xPages. Now, I'm working on a modular workflow unit that will run as a typical workflow backgrounder agent in future applications built on my framework.

Devs will have many possibilities how to modify a flow but one of them would be some kind of object rules. Therefore I'd like to use Java rather then Lotusscript but first I need to check if there are no performance penalties while running Java agents instead of LS agents.

So, did anyone do any performance testing in this area previously?

Thanks for any info. JiKra

Comment: For bulk processing I believe LotusScript is faster than Java but I can't back that up with any evidence, just hearsay.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that they're about the same. Bear in mind that the operations that take the most time -- opening databases, updating views, reading and writing documents -- these are done by the same lower level code. Compared to that, the amount of time it takes to assign variables in memory, do loops, and so on, is pretty small. I would use whatever's more convenient.

One consideration is that a lot more people know Java. However, LotusScript is an object-oriented language if you choose to use it that way.

Comment: Lotusscript does not know interfaces, generics and many other OOP stuff I'd like to use while building an API. So Java is the best choice, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If your workload is amenable to multi-threading, then Java is your best choice because you can do threads in Java and you can't in LotusScript.